# My Form Keeps Creating New Objects each time i open InGameForm and this cause high memory usage

Tags: winforms, memory-leaks, dispose

i am developing a quiz game. I have 2 forms. Form1 and InGameForm. From the Form1 you choose continent gamemode and minutes. After y click play InGameForm opens. The InGameForm loads to flags array a list of 196 images from resources.

```
Image[] flags = new Image[196] { Properties.Resources.Greece, Properties.Resources.United_Kingdom, ect ect super long line };
```

The problem:
Each time i switch back to form1 from ingameform and pick another or same continent and then click play it uses the double amount of memory. I quess it does because i create a new array of Image each time without disposing the last object. What can i do? [form1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvwMS.jpg) [InGameForm.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX2gD.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you know what you have to do. -- In the sample image you posted, you have a background image and, apparently,  another image representing a flag: do you really need to load all the flags beforehand? Maybe show just the current, then dispose of it before you show another, and so on.

Comment: I think i have to load all the images to array because i use a random method to create 196 random unique numbers from [0 to 195] in random order, in order to use flags[random[i]] inside a loop to show random flags example
```
for (i=0; i<196; i++) {
  picturebox1.Image = flags[random[i]];
}
```

Comment: You probably just need a collection of strings, get a random one, then use `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject()` to retrieve the Image by name. -- I also suggest to store the Image as Resources in a satellite assembly, not your main executable. You can add to this assembly static methods that allow to retrieve resources by name, index, create groups based on *keywords* etc.

Comment: You could also store those string in the Projects Settings, or a JSON file or something similar, so you don't need to hard-code those names in your executable and recompile each time you need to change something.

Comment: Since you already know it's an array memory leak, why not free it when you're done using it? For example, wrap it up with Using, etc.